# Most advanced tutorial on custom collection editor

Tags: .net, customization, system.componentmodel, collectioneditor

We need to know everything on how to customize the standard .NET collection editor, where shall we look?

Comment: Have you ever found a good soultion for this?  I'm in the same boat you where in 3 years ago...

Comment: There absolutely no doc on the subject. We gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Windows forms programming in C#]

- [Windows forms programming in C#](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=YtHimzwqpi4C&lpg=PA640&ots=pRLLyl2vfn&dq=collection%20editor%20chris%20sells&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)  By *Chris Sells*
- [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dzcollectioneditor.aspx)

Comment: @AB Kolan: We need to go far beyond this level, sorry.

Comment: How far beyond ? What are your requirements ?

Comment: @AB Kolan: For example changing the Add button to a DropDown list supporting different type of objects to be added.

Comment: Have you looked at Chapter 7,8,9 of this book ?

Comment: In that case you would require something a little more advanced than the collection editor. An [UI Type Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx) may be?

Comment: @AB Kolan: Yes, we own this book. No, I am talking about the collection editor dialog. When you edit a collection you see a standard dialog with tha Add and Remove buttons. I saw that the Add button can be customized.

Comment: [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dzcollectioneditor.aspx) on CodeProject

Comment: @AB Kolan: Yes, this explain the feature we are looking for, thanks.